# CakePHP - Auth to save user's last login time

Tags: cakephp, authentication

Where is the best place to insert the code to save the user's last login?  I am using the CakePHP Auth login system in almost the standard implementation in the manual.

Where can I insert the code so that it will save to the User record just before Auth redirects after login?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to disable `AuthComponent::autoRedirect` if you wish for the code in your `UsersController::login()` method to execute:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        // ...
        'autoRedirect' => false,
    ),
);
```

You can then do this in your login action, but you will still need to perform the redirect manually:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->Auth->user()) { // check user is logged in
        $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id'); // target correct record
        $this->User->saveField('last_login', date(DATE_ATOM)); // save login time
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); // redirect to default place
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the login itself is still performed by the component. In my sites' `UsersController::login()` methods, I check for a login being attempted and a non-empty `$this->Auth->user()` before setting the `last_login` value. The only time I explicitly call `$this->Auth->login()` is after a successful signup and after updating auth user data on the fly.